# Oracle update from multiple tables

Tags: oracle, sql-update

I have an star schema with two fact tables, and several dimension tables.  I want to update one of the facts to be a sum of facts from both fact tables.  Assume I have data like:

```
Fact1:
Val1|Dim1|Dim2|Dim3|RunNB
100 |1   |2   |3   |1
200 |1   |2   |4   |1
101 |1   |2   |3   |2 

Fact2:
Val2|Val3|Dim1|Dim2|Dim3|RunNB
100 |0   |1   |2   |3   |3
200 |0   |1   |2   |4   |3
101 |0   |1   |2   |3   |4

Run:
RunNB|Date
1    |20150423
2    |20150428
3    |20150423
```

I want to populate Fact2.Val3 with Fact1.Val1 + Fact2.Val2, for all the rows where the dimensions match, and the date associated with the run is the same.

The following query selects the right data:

```
select Fact1.Val1 + Fact2.Val2
from Fact1, Fact2, Run r1, Run r2
where Fact1.Dim1 = Fact2.Dim1 AND
      Fact1.Dim2 = Fact2.Dim2 AND
      Fact1.Dim3 = Fact3.Dim3 AND
      Fact1.RunNB = r1.RunNB AND
      r1.Date = '20150423' AND
      Fact2.RunNB = r2.RunNB AND
      r2.Date = '20150423';
```

I need to select the sum, then update the appropriate Fact2.Val3 with the sum.  I'm having trouble constructing the update statement.

My understanding is that Oracle doesn't support:

```
update x
set y
FROM z
where q
```

I also tried the:

```
update (
  select ...
) set ...
```

syntax, but I'm not able to get anything working.  Can I use MERGE for this?  Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: This seems like a poor data model.  A star schema with two fact tables isn't a real star schema.  But two fact tables with the same dimensions and related facts?  Definitely smelly.  Also, if your fact tables hold proper  warehouse volumes you don't want to be running update statements on them (including merges).

Comment: Agreed. The task I'm trying to do does not make sense.  However, for various legacy reasons I need to do it.  I can't change either the data model, nor the requirement.  Do you have any ideas on how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

This `merge` statement worked for given examples:

```
merge into (select * from fact2 
  where runnb in (select runnb from run where rDate = '20150423')) f2
using (  
  select dim1, dim2, dim3, run.runnb, val1 
    from fact1 join run on fact1.runnb = run.runnb and rDate = '20150423' ) f1
on (f1.dim1 = f2.dim1 and f1.dim2 = f2.dim2 and f1.dim3 = f2.dim3) 
when matched then update set f2.val3 = f1.val1 + f2.val2;
```

In case there are more rows than one for dim1, dim2, dim3 for one day in table fact1 they have to be grouped and summed at first in `using` part, 
otherwise error *unable to get stable set of rows* may occur. 
BTW - I renamed `date` to `rdate` in table `run`.

Comment: Thanks.  When I implement this I get the following Oracle error: `Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-30926: unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables
30926. 00000 -  "unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables"
*Cause:    A stable set of rows could not be got because of large dml
           activity or a non-deterministic where clause.
*Action:   Remove any non-deterministic where clauses and reissue the dml.`  My real data set is much larger than the one in my example, but both select statements return the same number of records, without dupes.  Any ideas on the problem?

Comment: Update: I think I see the root cause the ORA-30926 error.  There are actually a few dupes (about 10 in 160000 records) due some issues with the  normalization of the data.  I suspect the query will work without those errors... Thanks.

Comment: As I warned you - this error means that for some rows exists duplicates for same (dim1, dim2, dim3, date) in `fact1`. Here is 
[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e331c/1), where I reproduced such situation, you can run query from the fiddle against your data to check it. 
For `merge` to run properly this query should not return any rows.
I added one row to `fact1`, that with val1=201. Now `merge` (nor me) does not know which row it has to use. Solution is to group data in inner query, but I do not know if you want this. Or eliminate dupes.